# Java after compiled will not draw the map layers

Tags: java, graphics, awt

For some reason when I compile my program it does not draw the map layers, however it does draw them if I debug or run from eclipse.  However after it when I run it as a independent jar file it does draw the player, just not the maps.

Can anyone take a look and tell me what on earth is going on?

for those who have problems downloading

Here is my ground.java

```
package com.ChimpyGames.Tile;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Ground {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private int tileSize;
    private int[][] map;
    public int mapWidth;
    public int mapHeight;

    public Ground(String s, int tileSize) {

        this.tileSize = tileSize;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/maps/" + s
                    + "/Ground.map"));

            mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            mapHeight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            map = new int[mapHeight][mapWidth];

            String delimiters = " ";
            for (int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                String[] tokens = line.split(delimiters);

                for (int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++) {
                    map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public static void update() {

    }

    public static void draw(Graphics g) {
        for (int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++) {

                int rc = map[row][col];

                if (rc == 0) {

                }
                if (rc == 1) {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.fillRect(x + col * tileSize, y + row * tileSize,
                            tileSize, tileSize);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Play.java

```
package com.ChimpyGames.Menus;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import com.ChimpyGames.GamePanel;
import com.ChimpyGames.Entities.Player;
import com.ChimpyGames.Handlers.Keys;
import com.ChimpyGames.Tile.Ground;
import com.ChimpyGames.Tile.Mask1;
import com.ChimpyGames.Tile.Mask2;
import com.ChimpyGames.Tile.Overlay1;
import com.ChimpyGames.Tile.Overlay2;
import com.ChimpyGames.Tile.Scripts;

public class Play extends Menu {
    Player player;
    private String map;
    public int tileSize;
    public Ground ground;
    public Mask1 mask1;
    public Mask2 mask2;
    public OVerlay1 overlay1;
    public Overlay2 overlay2;
    public Scripts scripts;

    public Play(MenuManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // load the map by it's folder not by the .map
        map = "DefaultMap";
        tileSize = 32;

        // Load Individual layers
        ground = new Ground(map, tileSize);
        mask1 = new Mask1(map, tileSize);
        mask2 = new Mask2(map, tileSize);
        overlay1 = new Overlay1(map, tileSize);
        overlay2 = new Overlay2(map, tileSize);
        scripts = new Scripts(map, tileSize);

        player = new Player();


    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        Ground.update();
        Mask1.update();
        Mask2.update();

        player.update();

        Overlay1.update();
        Overlay2.update();
        Scripts.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        handleInput();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.width, GamePanel.height);
        Ground.draw(g);
        Mask1.draw(g);
        Mask2.draw(g);
        // Keep above code at top

        player.draw(g);

        // Keep below code at bottom
        Overlay1.draw(g);
        Overlay2.draw(g);
        Scripts.draw(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput() {
        player.up(Keys.keyState\[Keys.UP\]);
        player.down(Keys.keyState\[Keys.DOWN\]);
        player.left(Keys.keyState\[Keys.LEFT\]);
        player.right(Keys.keyState\[Keys.RIGHT\]);

        if (Keys.keyState\[Keys.ENTER\]) {
        }
    }
}
```

Ran as executable
[image: Ran as executable]

Ran from eclipse
[image: Ran from eclipse]

Comment: Include the code and the images in the post, not in a non-permanent link.

Comment: It is also compiled when running from Eclipse. Stop trying to blame Java (in this one and the question you removed) and start trying to reason what you are doing wrong. As I suggest in the question you removed: it is probably in the way you load resources. But I can't see that because my corporate firewall does not allow me to go to pastebin.

Comment: @Gimby no where in here am I saying it's a compile problem I am explaining what is going on.   Does your corporate firewall allow any site similar to paste bin?   If not I can post the code here of you prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create an images or a maps folder right under your project.  Not in the source directory.
2. You need to make the images or maps folder part of your Java build path.
3. You need to read your maps like this.  One method per map.

---

```
public Image getFrameImage() {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "/package_games_board.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow Java naming convention `Ground Ground =`, That *doesn't* confuse you? Variables begin with lower case letters `Ground Ground` → `Ground ground`
2. Get rid of all the `static` in your `Ground` class. Those should all be instance methods and variable.
3. Make `Ground ground;` a class member (global). Currently it's locally scoped in the constructor. You may think that doing `Ground.draw(g);` is using the instance `Ground` but it doesn't. You are calling the `Ground` class method staticly, in which case all the variable called in your `draw` method are defaulted to 0
4. Same three points go for your other classes also that you call inside you `init` method.

---

```
public class Play {
    private Ground ground;

    public void inti() {
        ground = new Ground(...)
    }

    public void draw(...) {
        ground.draw(g);
    }
}
```

---

You really need to read some good tutorials on the difference between instance fields and methods and `static` fields and methods, and how to use them. You can start [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20the%20fox%20say#q=what+the+difference+between+static+and+instance+in+java)

Comment: Ya I am still pretty new.  I'm sure you could tell xD.  I will check the link out however I did what you said and it appears to be doing the same thing.   My maps/DefaultMap/layer.map. is in the src folder. Am I calling this wrong?

Comment: You need to change all the above points for _all_ your classes, not just the `Ground` class

Comment: I have changed them all.  I am not that new. xD  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved.  it was trying to get files externally.